# How to type  using laptop keyboard on Windows?

Tags: unicode, typing

I'd like to gain on the *funny guy* scale and let people know their are slow. Usually I do that by pasting something like "*hey, dude, don't be* " or when talking about *e-mail* versus *-mail*.

Usually, I copy that character by hand from [some webpage](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F40C) or [another one](https://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%90%8C) but it would be so much cooler to be able to  up the text without it.

Is there a way to "type" in  or similar on a laptop running Win 10 without specific software installed and without any special keys on the keyboard? I googled it a bit but the hints didn't work out or required some key combos that I can't see on my computer.

Comment: This question belongs on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Windows key and Period key at the same time to open the Windows Emoji Keyboard. Then type "snail" and enter to insert the snail emoji.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Win10 system. There is no Emoji keyboard installed

Comment: Ah, I see the problem:
"The emoji picker seems to only be available to users in the United States at the moment. Users who have en_US set as their device’s primary language will still be able to use the feature despite being outside of the US, though." https://mspoweruser.com/heres-new-emoji-picker-windows-10-might-not-work/

Comment: @RemyLebeau Strange. I got that working. And when I have Swedish keyboard activated I have to type *snigel* not *snail* whereas having English active requires *snail*. But it seems to work to get the emoji panel by Win+. Maybe you can try again? It was a bit lagged the first time on my machine too. What is your language of the system.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana I'm in the US and the Emoji keyboard simply doesn't work for me, neither "Win+." nor "Win+;" bring it up. I'll have to check if I am missing some updates

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can insert a Unicode character up to 255 decimal value by holding down alt and typing the decimal value on the numpad (if you have one) then releasing alt, this won't work for the snail though because it is higher than 255 (128012) so that rules out notepad from being able to do it. But apps like word and other rich text editors can enter Unicode characters by typing there unicode hex values then pressing alt+x so to get a snail you would type U+1f40c[ALT+x] (the U+ is optional) other than that it is up to each program to figure out how they want to do it if at all. Happy  ing!

Comment: ALT codes are not the same values as the Unicode codepoints they map to